# R with tcltk: Why should I add widgets to the parents env (environment) variable?

Tags: r, user-interface, tk-toolkit

When creating GUIs with the R package `tcltk` it seems to be a [best practice](http://www.sciviews.org/recipes/tcltk/TclTk-simple-toplevel-window/) to add child widgets to the parent's environment stored in the `env` variable of the parent, e. g.

```
library(tcltk)
win2 <- tktoplevel()
win2$env$butOK <- ttkbutton(win2, text = "OK", command = function() { tkdestroy(win2) })
tkgrid(win2$env$butOK, padx = 70, pady = 30)
```

The argument *"to avoid inflation of [tk widget related] variables in the global environment"* is absolutely correct, but I could achieve the same result **without using `env`** but storing the child widgets directly as variables of the parent. This seems to me a more natural OO-alike style and improves the readability:

```
win3 <- tktoplevel()
win3$butOK <- ttkbutton(win3, text = "OK", command = function() { tkdestroy(win3) })
tkgrid(win3$butOK, padx = 70, pady = 30)
```

**Question: Are there strong reasons to prefer the first version using the `env` variable?**

PS: M. Lawrence and J. Verzani demonstrated in their great book "Programming graphical user interfaces in R" (2012) an even more sophisticated (object-oriented) approach by encapsulating the widget and state variables in a reference class (see chapter 19.2) but this creates much more code than I need and adds complexity (to solve other problems too of course - that I don't have to solve - e. g. a generic look up of state variables in callback functions)

Comment: I thought adding widgets to the env variable could possible avoid copying the parent object (COW priciniple of R) but this is not the case: `> library(tcltk)
> library(pryr)  # for mem tracing
> win2 <- tktoplevel()
> address(win2)
[1] "0x3fdaff0"
> win2$env$butOK <- ttkbutton(win2, text = "OK", command = function() { tkdestroy(win2) })
> address(win2)
[1] "0x35e82c8"` I am still looking for an answer.